# Log into Microsoft Teams custom tab with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to use Firebase authentication in my Microsoft Teams app and I can't figure out how to get the sign in URL.

I'm following the Teams documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab).

The system they outline basically revolves around using the `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup()` method, but using the `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate()` method to handle opening the popup and responding to it. However, for that to work, I would need to pass the generated URL from `signInWithPopup` to `authenticate()`.

Is it possible to get the generated URL from `firebase.auth()`? Or can I manually construct the URL somehow?

Comment: when you call microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate you set the start page for your login flow that is your URL, firebase.auth() will not give you that URL you have to manually construct it.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT do you know of any documentation on how to manually construct the auth URL?